# Can't get shadow to appear with SCNLight

Tags: swift, scenekit, virtual-reality

I added in some ambient light, directional light, and a floor but still no shadow appears. Any idea why?

```
// create and add ambient light to the scene
let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.init(hexString: "ececec")
ambientLightNode.light!.intensity = 100
ambientLightNode.light!.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

// Main Light
let floor = SCNNode()
floor.geometry = SCNFloor()
floor.geometry?.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
floor.geometry?.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask(rawValue: 0)
floor.castsShadow = false
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floor)

// Create directional light
let directionalLight = SCNNode()
directionalLight.light = SCNLight()
directionalLight.castsShadow = true
directionalLight.light?.type = .directional
directionalLight.position = SCNVector3(2, 10, 2)

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(directionalLight)
```

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of what it looks like?  If you're following a tutorial, could you give us a screenshot of what it is *supposed* to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Set light's `castsShadow` property to `true` (it's `false` by default):

```
directionalNode.light?.castsShadow = true        // LIGHT's property
```

---

If you use node's `castsShadow` property, you can exclude a node from shadow map rendering:

```
modelNode.castsShadow = false                    // NODE's property
```

(it's `true` by default)